# About the default location of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Previously the default location when installing anaconda3 is

```
~/anaconda3
```

but today I uninstalled it and reinstalled it again, and the location became

```
~/opt/anaconda3
```

and I am having a lot of trouble with it. Is it possible to change the default location? I've already chose "Install for my own" (or something like that) while installing.